# how to get object_id from Post_id in from database in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am trying to build a theme and for that i need to write a query to get seo details from yoast.

I look into the table and i found every thing in yoast is mapped with object_id.

I am not able to figure out relation between post_id and object_id.

Can anyone write a query to help.

I tried to look into the table and on internet.
Internet has some function that fetch post specific details from yoast table.

I am trying to understand relation between post_id and object_id.

Can anyone write a query to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `get_post` function to return the post object and pull out the ID field. This property contains the object ID.

```
$post_id = 123; // Replace with the ID of the post
$post = get_post( $post_id );
$object_id = $post->ID;
```